# How to underline the last row before the counta total?

Tags: excel

so I figured this much:

```
    Dim myLastRow As Long

    'Find last row in column A
    myLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'   Insert count after last cell in column A
    Cells(myLastRow + 1, "A").Formula = "=COUNTA(A2:A" & myLastRow & ")"
```

This will count a Column and put the total on the bottom. but how do I underline the last row before the total?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
Dim myLastRow As Long

'Find last row in column A
myLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Insert count after last cell in column A
Cells(myLastRow + 1, "A").Formula = "=COUNTA(A2:A" & myLastRow & ")"

With Cells(myLastRow + 1, "A").Borders(xlEdgeTop)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlMedium
End With
```